# Returning an element from an ArrayList of collections, where each collection has a different element type

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, collections

I have an `ArrayList` of `BagWithRandomSelect` of different types.  So `arrayList.get(1)` can return a `BagWithRandomSelect<Integer>` object, while `arrayList.get(2)` could return a `BagWithRandomSelect<String>` object.  Is it possible to write a method to return an element from a `BagWithRandomSelect` as its own type, rather than return an `Object` that would need to be cast?

My question lies in the method `testGetFromColumn()`:

```
public class BagWithRandomSelect<E> {
    ArrayList<E> bag;
    public BagWithRandomSelect() {
        this.bag = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public void add(E element) {
        this.bag.add(element);
    }
    public E randomSelect() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int rndInt = this.rnd.nextInt(bag.size);
        return this.bag.get(rndInt);
    }
}

public class DatafileCreator {
    ArrayList<BagWithRandomSelect> columnList;
    public DatafileCreator() {
        this.columnList = new ArrayList<Stack>();
    }

    // skipping some methods...

    public void addNewColumn(BagWithRandomSelect bag, String s) {
        this.columnList.add(bag);
    }

    public Object testGetFromColumn(int columnNum) {
        BagWithRandomSelect<Object> bag = this.columnList.get(columnNum);
        return bag.randomSelect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried instanceof ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible but you have to know what type of object to expect. But since you have to cast anyways when using `Object` this should not be a problem.

```
public <T> T testGetFromColumn(int index, Class<T> clazz) {
    BagWithRandomSelect<?> bag = columnList.get(index);
    return clazz.cast(bag.randomSelect());
}
```

Note you have to have this explicit cast using the `Class` object here - a normal cast will not check if the cast is valid at runtime due to type erasure which turns `return (T) item;` into `return (Object) item;`. You can get really nasty bugs otherwise e.g.`ClassCastExceptions` with no cast present in the code where it fails.

You can then use the method like this:

```
DatafileCreator creator = ...;
...
String s = creator.testGetFromColumn(5, String.class);
Integer i = creator.testGetFromColumn(3, Integer.class);
```